# Кодер и декодер

Tags: binary

Здравствуйте! Буду краток, вот нашел ссылку по поводу двоичного кода: [ссылка](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_4.html)

Есть encoder и decoder. Пытался разобраться в статье, но на английском тяжеловато было разобраться, просветите меня по этой статье. Для чего можно использовать такую конструкцию? И можно ли её использовать для сжатия переменных со значениями в двоичной системе счисления?
Интересует 4-to-2 bit encoder и 2-to-4bit decoder. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: 1. это сайт программирования. Что значит по вашему разобраться?  Применимо к чему? 2. По моему всё понятно. encoder / decoder не имеют никакого отношения к сжатию данных. Другое название - подобных устройств - мультиплексор  дешифратор и шифратор. шифратор работает как антипод дешифратора. Таблицами их работа в статье хорошо отображена.

Comment: Дешифратор можно использовать, что б подавать еденичный сигнал на одно из 4-х устройств, используя 2-ва провода. Шифратор наоборот, позволяет, например, определить по 2-м проводам, какая из 4-х кнопок нажата при условие что нажата одна.

Answer (score 0):

> Мультиплексоры являются одними из наиболее часто используемых
> комбинационных схем. Они позволяют выбрать одно выходное значение из
> нескольких входных в зависимости от значения сигнала выбора.
>
> *Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера*.

[image: Схема работы мультиплексера]

Представьте, что Вы - дешифратор, я управляющий сигнал (`b`, `a`), а перед Вами - четыре кнопки, которые пропускают соответствующие сигналы: `A`, `B`, `C` и `D`.

Если я подам Вам сигнал `10`, то Вы нажмете кнопку `С` и на выход мультиплексера (`Q`) будет подан сигнал `C`.

Демультиплексер делает то же самое, только наоборот.